# How to plot a horizontal bar over a time series plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following data and chart in matplotlib:

```py
chart_ts = [datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 0),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 1),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 2),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 3),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 4),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 5),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 6),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 7),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 8),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 9)]

chart_close = [1.32034,
 1.32046,
 1.3205,
 1.32025,
 1.32025,
 1.32026,
 1.32034,
 1.32035,
 1.32035,
 1.32063]

mp_close = [1.320060, 1.320055, 1.320050, 1.320045, 1.320040, 1.320035, 1.320030, 1.320025]
mp_value = [5, 6, 8, 10, 3, 5, 6, 2]

%matplotlib inline
mpl.rcParams['interactive'] = False
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8, 8.0)

# plot
plt.plot(chart_ts,chart_close)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

By running above code I get this:

[image: Chart1]

So far, so good.

Now I want to plot mp_close and mp_value as horizontal bar over the first chart.
The desired result would be this (it is just a hand drawn mockup, not an accurate representation in terms of scale):

[image: Chart2]

**But if I just add the new plot I find that the X-axis used for both charts is not the same. How shall I achieve this result?**

Following @importanceofbeingernest comment, I have tried this:

```py
chart_ts = [datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 0),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 1),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 2),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 3),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 4),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 5),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 6),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 7),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 8),
 datetime(2013, 1, 1, 17, 9)]

chart_close = [1.32034,
 1.32046,
 1.3205,
 1.32025,
 1.32025,
 1.32026,
 1.32034,
 1.32035,
 1.32035,
 1.32063]

mp_close = [1.320060, 1.320055, 1.320050, 1.320045, 1.320040, 1.320035, 1.320030, 1.320025]
mp_value = [5, 6, 8, 10, 3, 5, 6, 2]

%matplotlib inline
mpl.rcParams['interactive'] = False
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8, 8.0)

# plot
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.plot(chart_ts,chart_close)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.barh(mp_close, mp_value, align='center')

plt.show()
```

But I get:

[image: Chart3]

Now I suspect I am close to get it but I would miss:

- How to scale horizontally the second chart, so maximum value at the right side of the chart would be 20 for example.
- The width of the horizontal bars seems to be too wide.

For the width of the bar I have tried this:

```
ax2.barh(mp_close, mp_value, align='center', width=0.00003)
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: barh() got multiple values for argument 'width'
```

Comment: Read about twin axes, in this case `ax.twiny()`. [Here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html) is an example.

Comment: @importanceofbeingernest Thanks for the hint, if I understood the description, in this case it would be a call for `ax2 = ax1.twinx()`. The first figure has datetimes as x axis, and the second one has a scalar. This generates the following message: `ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units`. Also I am wondering if it might be needed to specify the width of the horizontal bars.

Comment: No, I said `twiny()`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for clarifying, now I get it why it is `twiny`. Following your comment I have edited the question. I think I am missing how to set up the width of the horizontal bar and scale the second chart (so a value of 10 would be for example in the middle of the chart, although I guess that could be done setting a maximum and minimum values for ax2)

Comment: I discovered I needed to modify the `height` instead of the `width` for being horizontal bars. Also there were an additional zero in the test data. Now it works. Thanks for the help.